# How to append a letter in column values access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table

```
 Name     Description       EID  

 name1      ssdad          1001
 name2      gfd            1002
 name3      gfdsffsdf      1003
 name4      ssdad          1004
 name5      gfd            1005
 name6      gfdsffsdf      1006
```

i want to append **C** letter for EID's 1001,1002,1003 only. How to specify that in sql query. Like C1001,C1002,C1003.

```
 Name     Description       EID  

 name1      ssdad          C1001
 name2      gfd            C1002
 name3      gfdsffsdf      C1003
 name4      ssdad          1004
 name5      gfd            1005
 name6      gfdsffsdf      1006
```

Comment: Append during select or update the table?

Comment: That's a good question but I didn't understand it right away.  REPHRASE:  Is your goal to merely display EID with a `C`, or is it to change the value of EID in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're targeting only 3 values, you could include them in a list.

```sql
SELECT
    EID,
    IIf(EID In ('1001','1002','1003'), 'C', '') & EID AS adjusted_EID
FROM YourTable;
```

If you actually want to change the stored values, you can use that list in the  `WHERE` clause of an `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET EID = 'C' & EID
WHERE EID In ('1001','1002','1003');
```

If you had many more target values, such a list would become unwieldy.  In that case, you might prefer a different approach to check whether the current value is one of your target values.

Comment: How do i specify that in **UPDATE** statement instead of **SELECT**

Comment: I have to update only 4 values. It says **EID** cannot be updatable

Comment: Now things are more interesting :-)

Comment: SELECT is fine then. Thank you so much.

Comment: I loaded your data into a table in Access 2007 and that `UPDATE` worked without error.  My `EID` field is text datatype.  If yours is numeric, it won't accept a value which includes "C".

Comment: My **EID** is text, I have more than 500 rows, but doen't matter how many rows right.

Comment: No, the number of rows should not matter.  I don't see why your `EID` is not updatable.

Comment: @vuyy1182 - what's the text length on your `EID` column? It needs to be at least 5 for the update to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use IIF to check a condition and then do something accordingly. In your case, you can check if `EID` is less than 1004, and append 'C' to the result if it is. So if you want to only select, query will be:

```
select name, description, IIF(val(EID) < 1004, "C" & EID, EID) 
from yourtable
```

If you are updating just change it to

```
update yourtable 
set EID = "C"& EID 
where val(EID) < 1004
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET EID = "C" & [EID]
WHERE (Mid([EID],4,1)="1"
   OR Mid([EID],4,1)="2"
   OR Mid([EID],4,1)="3");
```

Comment: "similar to" is not precise enough to answer. What is your criteria? In any case, I think you should learn to apply filtering because it is very simple in this case.  Well, I assume it is ... based on the scant information.  I could be wrong; no way to know.

Comment: back to learning to filter in SQL: You now have three answers with different approaches, so that is a lot to go on. Which is best depends on the criteria you want to apply!